# How to show this Ricatti equation can be changed into a linear equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Problem:** The equation $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = A(x) y^2 + B(x) y + C(x) $$ is called a Ricatti equation. Suppose a partical solution is given as $y_1 (x)$. Show that the substitution $$ y = y_1 + \frac{1}{v} $$ transforms the Ricatti equation into the linear equation $$ \frac{dv}{dx} + (B + 2A y_1) v = -A. $$

**Attempt:** Since $y_1 (x)$ is a solution, we must have $$ y_1 (x) = A(x) y_1^2 + B(x) y_1 + C(x). $$ Now we have $$ y_1' = \left(y - \frac{1}{v}\right)' = y' + \frac{1}{v^2}. $$ I plugged this in and got $$ \left(y' + \frac{1}{v^2}\right) = A(x) \left(y - \frac{1}{v}\right)^2 + B(x) \left(y - \frac{1}{v}\right) + C(x) $$ or \begin{align*} A(x) y^2 + B(x) y + C(x) + \frac{1}{v^2} = A(x) y^2 - 2 \frac{y}{v} A(x) + \frac{1}{v^2} A(x) + B(x) y - B(x) \frac{1}{v} + C(x). \end{align*} After simplification this gives me \begin{align*} \frac{1}{v} (1 - A(x)) = (-2 y A(x) - B(x)). \end{align*}
Now I'm not sure what to do, should I differentiate $v$? Were all my previous steps correct?

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation

Comment: it calls Riccati

Comment: You forgot a $v'$ and need to eliminate $y, y'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in your calculus. The affliction of the apostrophe as symbol of derivative !
[image]

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = A(x) y^2 + B(x) y + C(x) $$ 
$$ y = y_1 + \frac{1}{v} $$ 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy_1}{dx}-\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{dv}{dx} = A(x) \left(y_1 + \frac{1}{v}\right)^2 + B(x) \left(y_1 + \frac{1}{v}\right) + C(x) $$
$$ \frac{dy_1}{dx} = A(x) y_1^2 + B(x) y_1 + C(x) $$
$$\left(A(x) y_1^2 + B(x) y_1 + C(x)\right)-\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{dv}{dx} = A(x) \left(y_1 + \frac{1}{v}\right)^2 + B(x) \left(y_1 + \frac{1}{v}\right) + C(x) $$

$$ -\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{dv}{dx} = 2A(x)y_1\frac{1}{v} +A(x)\frac{1}{v^2} + B(x) \left( \frac{1}{v}\right)  $$

$$ \frac{dv}{dx} = -2A(x)y_1v -A(x) - B(x)v   $$
$$ \frac{dv}{dx}+\left(B(x)+2A(x)y_1\right)v  = -A(x) $$

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know I had to apply the chain rule to the function $v$.

Comment: The derivation is performed relatively to $x$, not relatively to $v$.